# javascript function in c# Page_Load

Tags: javascript, c#

I have a c# I am writing and I can not figure out how to properly put the entire function in the c#. I know I can put it in a .js and call it, however, there are two images in it that are being called from the database and will change for each while. I believe the best place to put this is in my sql connection call.

What it comes down to is being able to run my javascript function directly in the c#.

Here is how I thought it might work and correct me where I am wrong please:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,GetType(),"function","function();",true);
    (function() 
        {
            blah blah blah
        });
```

This is all tucked in to the void Page_Load within my SqlConnection argument... Or I may be way off and not able to put javascript in line. I appreciate the insight. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare your function in string and after that put it as attribute of `RegisterStartupScript`.

```
string jsFunction = @"
(function(); 
        {
            //your js code which should be executed
        });
";
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "function", jsFunction, true);
```

You can read [**ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript Method (Type, String, String, Boolean)**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y(v=vs.110).aspx). There is a detail example of how to do it.

Comment: Crap... I knew that :/ Thanks, still learning and I haven't used a lot of these enough. Will mark once timer allows.